# VirtualBox port forwarding with Packer

Tags: virtualbox, packer

I'm creating a VirtualBox image using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/).

Afterwards I start the VM and I'd like to use ssh to connect to it.
I know how to enable port forwarding [using the GUI](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) but I prefer to automate things, so I'm looking for a way to let Packer do that for me.

I'm using NAT as the way of connecting my VM to the network.

How do I tell Packer to forward some ports to the VM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After having a look at how to enable port forwarding using VirtualBox' commandline tool [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward), I came up with this configuration in my `packerConfig.json`:

```
"type": "virtualbox-iso",
"vboxmanage": [
   [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "1024" ],
   [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "1" ],
   [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--natpf1", "guest_ssh,tcp,,3022,,22" ]
 ]
...
```

The last part makes VirtualBox forward traffic from the host's 3022 to the guest's 22.

This means I can do `ssh -p 3022 me@127.0.0.1` to connect to the VM.

Answer (score 1):

To create a Port forward in VirtualBox with Packer, used this:

```
     [
         "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--natpf1", "name,tcp,ipHost,portHost,IpGuest,PortGuest"
     ]
```